# FFT strong signal in middle frequency bin

Tags: fft, finite-impulse-response, window-functions, radar

I've developed a radar that I'm using to determine the distance to remote objects. It uses a custom PCB with an onboard FPGA that performs the DSP algorithms. The data from it is then plotted on a host PC. This appears as a 2D histogram where the y-axis denotes the FFT frequency bins (due to the nature of the radar this is proportional to distance) and the x-axis denotes time. The plot (shown below) gives a very strong signal at a distance halfway between the antenna and max range, which I'm unable to explain.

[image]

The actual algorithms performed are: an FIR polyphase decimation filter (downsamples from 40MHz to 2MHz) which produces an output 1024 samples in length. Then I run it through a Kaiser window function with a beta of 6, followed by a 1024-point FFT, the result of which is transmitted to the host PC. For each value of t in the plot (the x-axis) the host PC averages over 30 1024-length sequences (averaged element-wise). Since all inputs to the FFT are real, the output is Hermitian symmetric and so I only plot the first 512 values of each output sequence. The strong signal you see above occurs at bins 257 and 258 (indexed from 0). I've tested the radar in an open space where it shouldn't generate any strong signals. I've simulated all of the FPGA logic, so while I can't be sure it's right (I've only formally verified parts of it), I'd be surprised if it wasn't.

What could be the cause of this? Is there some obvious aspect I'm missing? If any of this is unclear or some part of the information I've omitted is important for answering this question (e.g. the equation relating frequency to distance), please let me know and I'll include it.

---

Edit: *more details on acquired signal*

This is an FMCW radar. A frequency synthesizer generates sawtooth ramps from 5.3GHz to 5.9GHz over a duration of 1ms. This signal is simultaneously transmitted and mixed back in with the reflected signal. We then measure the difference frequency to back out the distance.

The FPGA modules are timed such that data is only acquired during the synthesizer's ramp period. First, I enable the ramp and power amplifier and (once enabled) begin acquiring data. The data is processed by the FIR filter and then passed through the kaiser window. Once the last sample passes through the FIR filter the ramp and power amplifier are disabled. The processed data (which were stored in a FIFO) are now run through the FFT and then the resulting output is dispatched in packets to the host PC via USB. I use a header sequence, tail sequence, and duplicated packets to try to avoid data corruption/loss. Once the FFT is finished, the process starts again (ramp and power amp enable, etc.).

The FIR filter should take just longer than 0.5ms to acquire all samples, so it should fall within the frequency ramp period.

Comment: Interesting, so if I follow, this is suggesting the presence of a strong 500 KHz tone- I don't see from your processing what would create this but suggests an aliasing imaging artifact in the process. Or occurs naturally in the radar processing (are you doing FMCW and can you provide more specifics on that?). Without other obvious answers I would suggest capturing your signal at various stages in the process to narrow down where this is being introduced. Are you able to easily do that? (Capture the raw 40 MHz signal and do your own FFT on that waveform, then the 2 MHz output.

Comment: What is the repetition rate of your FM chirps? Is this an expected high frequency component that you are supposed to filter out?

Comment: @DanBoschen I've added some information about the signal generation / processing. Let me know if there's anything else that would be useful to include. And thanks for the suggestion, that seems like a logical way to go about this. I'll update the post with any information I find doing that.

Comment: Have you also tested your FFT processing with test data (such as a  20 KHz sine wave?). I don't see in your processing how you would end up with a strong tone at 500 KHz, which if I follow your description is what you see in the FFT.

Comment: @DanBoschen you follow correctly, the tone is 500KHz. I haven't done that. Just computer simulations with randomized data. I guess I could store a sine wave in ram onboard the fpga and then run that through the FFT as a sense check. Seems like a good idea.

Comment: Let us know how it works out! If I follow correctly, you have a range resolution of about 20"?

Comment: I calculated less, about 0.5m (1.6"). Nyquist freq=1MHz, 512 bins, $d=c \times t_{ramp} \times \Delta f/(2\times f_{ramp})$. framp is 600MHz and tramp is 1ms, nyquist + bins give $\Delta f$ of 2KHz. How'd you arrive at 20"? Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Probably not since it has been a while since I've worked on FMCW radar, so checking if I could remember how to calculate it correctly: This is what I did, where am I going wrong?  I used your frequency resolution given your FFT and window choice as 1/1ms*2 (The Kaiser window with Beta = 6 approximately doubles the main-lobe) = 2 KHz.  I translated this to delay resolution: 2KHz/600MHz * 1ms duration = 3.33 ns, I then used the approximate propogation in free-space of 1 ns/foot (2ns/foot round trip), to arrive a 3.33ns/2ns =  1.7'  or 20"

Comment: Actually if you calculated 0.5m then 0.5m IS 20"!

Comment: hah yep its the same! not sure how i read `"` as feet...

Comment: I should just stick with metric and noboday would be confused. Glad I understand it still.

Comment: Is it a simple DC bias?

Comment: What's your PRF? I'm ruling out DC signals here since your erroneous return is not at 0 frequency (assuming you are mixing with the LO correctly). If your system is powered by a switching power supply that is not synchronized to the PRF (or multiples of), then you may get reliable spurs over time as seen in your histogram.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I don't believe it's a DC bias for the reason Envidia mentions.

Comment: @Envidia is that relevant for FMCW (genuine question, I'm new to radar)? I measure the received signals at the same time I'm sending the transmit signal. I.e. it's not a send pulse, turn off transmitter, measure received signal setup. The PRF ends up being around 1-2KHz but it's based on the amount of the time the fft and other algos take to run, not some deliberate decision. This is not synchronized to the switching frequency of my power supply. The switching frequency of the buck converter upstream of the mixer is 500KHz, which is the frequency of the tone. You think that could be the issue?

Comment: @MattHusz You're right, FMCW systems don't have a "PRF-proper", but they do have an equivalent as you mentioned. The power supply at 500 KHz might explain why you're seeing that tone in your histogram. If you can, try and get a different power supply that switches at a different frequency and check results. Also as a tidbit, this is one of the weaknesses of FMCW systems: they are vulnerable to electronic attack.

Comment: The power supply appears to be the issue thanks @Envidia for the suggestion. It was tough because I don't have a great scope, but I was able to measure noise of a few mV at 500KHz. That's enough to be picked up by my 12-bit ADC. Unfortunately I haven't been able to test a new power supply yet, but that's in the works.

Comment: @MattHusz Awesome! It would be great if you could follow-up with your new results!

Comment: @Envidia Will do!

Comment: Thanks for the debugging suggestions @DanBoschen! It helped me narrow this down as a hardware issue. It also forced me to make this design much more introspective/robust and I fixed several other issues in the process.

Comment: Ah that's good news. @Envidia you should put that as an answer (Summarizing how you connected the 500 KHz to a switching power supply) that he can select to close this open question. (Although that said this would belong on the electronics site and maybe there is a way to move it over to there--- still good I think to have it closed with a good answer).

Comment: @MattHusz Glad you figured it out. Yes is any FPGA development I plan ahead in the early design for signal test and injection points for this very purpose; ideally tied to system verification models for simulation and bench verification. In transceiver designs (which could carry to radar designs) I also check SNR metrics along the signal path as especially with fixed point designs there is a lot of opportunity to degrade the signal in obscure ways-- -just because your data path is N bits wide does not mean you are actually getting that dynamic range!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is powered by a switching power supply that is not synchronized to the PRF (or multiples of), then you may get reliable spurs over time as seen in your histogram.

In your case, it's been found that was indeed the problem! The 500 KHz frequency fell nicely in the middle of your 1 MHz histogram. Hopefully this will help hunt down similar issues in the future.